# How can create http watcher plugin with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to trigger the a webpack workflow with the http trigger, as a webhook instead of in the same time to file system event.
Is is possible to build this kind of workflow with webpack and his plugins ?

```
Http request           |                |
   +---------------->  |   Http         |
                       |   Watcher      +----------+
                       |                |          |
                       |                |          |         +---------------------+
                       |                |          |         |                     |
                       +----------------+          |         |                     |
                                                   |         |                     |
                                                   +-------> |                     |
                                                   |         |       WebPack       |
                                                   |         |         end         |
                                                   |         |       Plugins       |
                       +----------------+          |         |                     |
                       |                |          |         |                     |
                       |   Files        |          |         +---------------------+
Files system event     |   System       |          |
     +---------------> |   Watcher      +----------+
                       |                |
                       |                |
                       +----------------+
```

Thank you in advance for your advises.

Comment: It is possible by using webpack as api and not with the cli.
You will get a compiler instance that can trigger new compilation.

Comment: thank you for your answer @felixmosh, have you some example. I try to take https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/bin/webpack-dev-server.js for inspiration.

Comment: This is excellent inspiration!

Comment: The answer : Is finally not possible to run build with another way in the same times when the file system watcher is enabled `--watch`.  Well I finally done this with an ugly hack, you can set the flag `compiler.running` to `false` an run the compilation anyway ... do not reproduce at home.